# I2C_SLAVE ioctl purpose

Tags: linux, driver, i2c

I am writing code for implementing a simple `i2c` read/write function using the general linux `i2c` driver `linux/i2c-dev.h`

I am confused about the `ioctl` : `I2C_SLAVE`

The kernel documentation states as follows :

> You can do plain i2c transactions by using read(2) and write(2) calls.
>   You do not need to pass the address byte; instead, set it through
>   ioctl I2C_SLAVE before you try to access the device

However I am using the `ioctl I2C_RDWR` where I again set the slave address  using `i2c_msg.addr`.

The kernel documentation also mentions the following :

> Some ioctl() calls are for administrative tasks and are handled by
>   i2c-dev directly. Examples include I2C_SLAVE

So is it must to use the `ioctl I2C_SLAVE`? If so do I need to set it just once or every time I perform a read and write?

If I had an `i2c` device I could have just tested the code on the device and would not have bothered you guys but unfortunately I don't have one right now.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are three major methods of communicating with i2c devices from userspace.

#### 1. IOCTL I2C_RDWR

This method allows for simultaneous read/write and sending an uninterrupted sequence of message. Not all i2c devices support this method.

Before performing i/o with this method, you should check whether the device supports this method using an ioctl `I2C_FUNCS` operation.

Using this method, you *do not* need to perform an ioctl `I2C_SLAVE` operation -- it is done behind the scenes using the information embedded in the messages.

#### 2. IOCTL SMBUS

This method of i/o is more powerful but the resulting code is more verbose. This method can be used if the device does not support the `I2C_RDWR` method.

Using this method, you *do* need to perform an ioctl `I2C_SLAVE` operation (or, if the device is busy, an `I2C_SLAVE_FORCE` operation).

#### 3. SYSFS I/O

This method uses the basic file i/o system calls [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) and [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write). Uninterrupted sequential operations are not possible using this method. This method can be used if the device does not support the `I2C_RDWR` method.

Using this method, you *do* need to perform an ioctl `I2C_SLAVE` operation (or, if the device is busy, an `I2C_SLAVE_FORCE` operation).

I can't think of any situation when this method would be preferable to others, unless you need the chip to be treated like a file.

---

#### Full IOCTL Example

I haven't tested this example, but it shows the conceptual flow of writing to an i2c device.-- automatically detecting whether to use the ioctl `I2C_RDWR` or smbus technique.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define I2C_ADAPTER "/dev/i2c-0"
#define I2C_DEVICE  0x00

int i2c_ioctl_write (int fd, uint8_t dev, uint8_t regaddr, uint16_t *data, size_t size)
{
    int i, j = 0;
    int ret;
    uint8_t *buf;
    // the extra byte is for the regaddr
    size_t buff_size = 1 + size;

    buf = malloc(buff_size);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    buf[j ++] = regaddr;
    for (i = 0; i < size / sizeof(uint16_t); i ++) {
        buf[j ++] = (data[i] & 0xff00) >> 8;
        buf[j ++] = data[i] & 0xff;
    }

    struct i2c_msg messages[] = {
        {
            .addr = dev,
            .buf = buf,
            .len = buff_size,
        },
    };

    struct i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data payload = {
        .msgs = messages,
        .nmsgs = sizeof(messages) / sizeof(messages[0]),
    };

    ret = ioctl(fd, I2C_RDWR, &payload);
    if (ret < 0) {
        ret = -errno;
    }

    free (buf);
    return ret;
}

int i2c_ioctl_smbus_write (int fd, uint8_t dev, uint8_t regaddr, uint16_t *data, size_t size)
{
    int i, j = 0;
    int ret;
    uint8_t *buf;

    buf = malloc(size);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size / sizeof(uint16_t); i ++) {
        buf[j ++] = (data[i] & 0xff00) >> 8;
        buf[j ++] = data[i] & 0xff;
    }

    struct i2c_smbus_ioctl_data payload = {
        .read_write = I2C_SMBUS_WRITE,
        .size = I2C_SMBUS_WORD_DATA,
        .command = regaddr,
        .data = (void *) buf,
    };

    ret = ioctl (fd, I2C_SLAVE_FORCE, dev);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        ret = -errno;
        goto exit;
    }

    ret = ioctl (fd, I2C_SMBUS, &payload);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        ret = -errno;
        goto exit;
    }

exit:
    free(buf);
    return ret;
}

int i2c_write (int fd, uint8_t dev, uint8_t regaddr, uint16_t *data, size_t size)
{
    unsigned long funcs;

    if (ioctl(fd, I2C_FUNCS, &funcs) < 0) {
        return -errno;
    }

    if (funcs & I2C_FUNC_I2C) {
        return i2c_ioctl_write (fd, dev, regaddr, data, size);
    } else if (funcs & I2C_FUNC_SMBUS_WORD_DATA) {
        return i2c_ioctl_smbus_write (fd, dev, regaddr, data, size);
    } else {
        return -ENOSYS;
    }
}

int parse_args (uint8_t *regaddr, uint16_t *data, size_t size, char *argv[])
{
    char *endptr;
    int i;

    *regaddr = (uint8_t) strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 0);
    if (errno || endptr == argv[1]) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size / sizeof(uint16_t); i ++) {
        data[i] = (uint16_t) strtol(argv[i + 2], &endptr, 0);
        if (errno || endptr == argv[i + 2]) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void usage (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s regaddr data [data]*\n", argv[0]);
    fprintf(stderr, "  regaddr   The 8-bit register address to write to.\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "  data      The 16-bit data to be written.\n");
    exit(-1);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint8_t regaddr;
    uint16_t *data;
    size_t size;
    int fd;
    int ret = 0;

    if (argc < 3) {
        usage(argc, argv);
    }

    size = (argc - 2) * sizeof(uint16_t);
    data = malloc(size);
    if (data == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(ENOMEM));
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    if (parse_args(&regaddr, data, size, argv) != 0) {
        free(data);
        usage(argc, argv);
    }

    fd = open(I2C_ADAPTER, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    ret = i2c_write(fd, I2C_DEVICE, regaddr, data);
    close(fd);

    if (ret) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(-ret));
    }

    free(data);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Example code uses `sizeof(data)` when `data` is a pointer, which always returns sizeof pointer (4 or 8 on common OSes). You need to pass size of data, can't use `sizeof` like this!

Comment: Could you please add execution sample command?.. That will be more helpfull.

Comment: @hyde (much delayed, but...) you're right. i've updated the code sample to remove this bug.

Comment: @Naresh ./program 0xD 0x1337 0xdead 0xbeef
(see also the usage function)

Comment: I still find ioctl() confusing. When I do an ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, address) for every address between 0 and 127 I get a successful result. However when I do i2c_smbus_write_quick(fd, address) I only get a successful result if there is an actual I2C device there.  It's the second behavior I was looking for, but now I am completely confused as to what the ioctl function does. Why do I need it?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `read()` and `write()` methods, calling `ioctl` with `I2C_SLAVE` once is enough. You can also use `I2C_SLAVE_FORCE` if the device is already in use.

However I haven't yet found a consistent way to read specific registers for every device using the `read()/write()` methods.

Comment: Thanx for the info,but like i mentioned i am using I2C_RDWR ioctl,so do i need to use I2C_SLAVE ioctl?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure if this helps because I don't use ioctl I2C_RDWR but I've been using the following code with success:

```
int fd;
fd = open("/dev/i2c-5", O_RDWR);
ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE_FORCE, 0x20);
i2c_smbus_write_word_data(fd, ___, ___);
i2c_smbus_read_word_data(fd, ___);
```

All I do is set I2C_SLAVE_FORCE once at the beginning and I can read and write as much as I want to after that.

PS - This is just a code sample and obviously you should check the returns of all of these functions.  I'm using this code to communicate with a digital I/O chip.  The two i2c_* functions are just wrappers that call ioctl(fd, I2C_SMBUS, &args); where args is a struct i2c_smbus_ioctl_data type.

Comment: Why is I2C_SLAVE_FORCE working and not I2C_SLAVE (in the case where it's the first time we use the driver) ?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked on I2C code but the program that I was working one was a userland program for a custom embedded board.  I'm guessing that a driver was already attached to the device and that's why I was using _FORCE.

Answer (score 0):

For the interested, SLAVE_FORCE is used when the device in question is already being managed by a kernel driver. (i2cdetect will show UU for that address)